# How to support secure creation of a user account over an external API via a queued job?

Tags: api, security, encryption, queue, job-scheduling

**So this question is delving into security and encryption and the problem potentially hasn't been encountered by many. Answers may be theoretical. Let me outline the scenario...**

1. A website frontend is driven via a backend API. The backend has an endpoint handling a generic registration form with `username` and `password`. It's using SSL.
2. The backend API handles registration via an async job queue. The queue *does not* return responses to the API server. It's a set and forget operation to queue up the registration.
3. Queued jobs are picked up by workers. The workers take care of creating the user account. These workers need access to the plaintext user password so that they can trigger a third-party API registration call with the password.

**So the real crux of the problem is the syncing of the password to the third party API while not revealing it to prying eyes. The queue poses the problem of not having direct access to the plaintext password from global POST data anymore, meaning it needs to be stored in some fashion in the queue.**

The queue can easily store the hashed password and copy it directly to the users table. This solution does not allow for syncing of the password with the third party API, however, as it's already encrypted. I toyed with two-way encryption, but am whole-heartedly concerned with leaving the password prone to decryption by an attacker.

**Can anybody think of a secure way to handle this scenario of password syncing?**

The queue is a requirement and it's assumed that this is readable by anyone with access to the server. The passwords don't necessarily have to be synced; the password for the third-party API could be a derivation of the original so long as there's a secure means to decrypt via the logged in user without supplying their password. This is essentially to simulate Single Sign-On with a third party API that does not support SSO.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to sync passwords:

1. Both auth stores use reversible encryption so that each system can extract the real values to send to the other system;
2. Both use the exact same encryption so that you send the encrypted text through and therefore can be understood by both.
3. One system is the "master" in which the users always authenticate through and the "slave" systems simply receive acknowledgement that the user has logged in.  This can take the form of machine generated passwords created by the master for use in account creation on the slaves.
4. One system is the "master" that all other systems make calls into for account validation.  Similar to using LDAP or MyOpenID.

There are certainly issues you can run into with a multi-master password sync'ing such as ensuring password changes are properly replicated when a user changes their password.

In your case, it sounds like the user never directly interfaces with the 3rd party API.  If that's accurate, have the users authenticate against your system.  Generate the 3rd party API password when needed, store it with their account and auto log them into the other system as necessary.  Your primary password can be stored in irreversible encryption; however the 3rd party one would have to use reversible encryption.  The Queue would never have to have the initial password and instead would simply generate a new one and store it with the local account.

Comment: I should add that I have no control over the third-party API; only the client and server API. The third-party API is separate from the server API. The expectation from the third-party API is that they receive a plaintext password during registration and that they also receive a plaintext password for logins. For the purposes of mimicking Single Sign-On, I can't ask the user for the password but are 100% sure of their logged in status.

Comment: @cballou: Then option 3 above sounds like what you want.  They sign into your system.  Your system makes the API call the 3rd party passing an unencrypted password.  Hopefully they at least have SSL.  Store the password using reversible encryption on your side.

Comment: Also, in regards to two-way encryption, it's not optimal for me unless there's a means of the decryption not being compromised by a root user. If my server was compromised, I'd fear the attacker would have full access to all third party accounts. While this wouldn't pose a problem for the user's primary password, it would definitely be a breach of security for those third-party account passwords and grant access.

Comment: @cballou: If the server is compromised then yes, they would be able to decrypt the passwords locally.  However, given that the third party doesn't offer a better way of dealing with this you don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Heck, if your server was compromised, a hacker could simply replace any hashed passwords and gain direct access to an account through your interface anyway.  Point is, if you've been "rooted" then you're pretty well screwed no matter what.  The only thing encrypting passwords buys you is the hope that it doesn't lead to yet other systems (not under your control) being hacked, like FB or paypal.

Comment: Yeah, I came to that conclusion myself. I'm going to hold out for a few days and see if I can get any answers out of left field on this one before accepting a solution.